Remote Desktop losing port assignment
I have a recent installation of Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 which is running headless, hence the need for a reliable remote access solution. I have been using the inbuilt Remote Desktop app however I have found that I am randomly unable to connect.
On checking the settings I noticed that the port number (3389) seems to disappear as per the image below. When I try to select the port number field, I get a "Port Number copied" message and am unable to add the port number again.
A restart seems to be the only way to resolve the issue but this is not a long-term solution so I would appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks.

